# Change not able to update on commentsRef.on("child_changed", (data) => {

Tags: reactjs, firebase-realtime-database

Hi I am using firebase with react, the issue when I am trying to use

```
  commentsRef.limitToLast(1).on("child_changed", (data) => {
     
        if (guests) {
          const key = data.key;
          const updatedGuest = data.val();
//guests ->isnt updated from last trigger
          const cloneGuests =_.cloneDeep(guests);
          cloneGuests.forEach((element, index) => {
            if (element.guestID === key) {
              cloneGuests[index] = updatedGuest;
            }
          });
          setGuests(cloneGuests);
        }
      });
```

and I am trying to use guests with my prev state and the new data, the issue that prev state isnt updated because the trigger of firebase is faster then change state,

Answer (score 1):

you can debounce the react paint and que the updates

```
let changes = [];
const storeData = (changedData) => {
           changes.push({
                  key: changedData.key,
                  updatedGuest: changedData.val()
           });
}

const updateDisplay = () => {
       for (canst guest in storeData){
            const cloneGuests =_.cloneDeep(guests);
              cloneGuests.forEach((element, index) => {
                if (element.guestID === key) {
                  cloneGuests[index] = updatedGuest;
                }
              });
            }
              setGuests(cloneGuests);
              changes  = [];
  

}

commentsRef.limitToLast(1).on("child_changed", (data) => {
        if (guests) {
          storeData(guests);
          debounce(updateDisplay,500);
        }
      });
```